# Inactive and active PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Having problem to change the state if its active or inactive everytime I clicked one of them nothings happened.

This is my code on ajax.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.status_checks',function(){
      var status = ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) ? '0' : '1';
      var msg = (status=='0')? 'Deactivate' : 'Activate';
      if(confirm("Are you sure to "+ msg)){
        var current_element = $(this);
        url = "ajax.php";
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: url,
          data: {id:$(current_element).attr('data'),status:status},
          success: function(data)
          {   
            location.reload();
          }
        });
      }      
    });
</script>
```

my php code ajax.php

```
<?php $db= new mysqli('localhost','root','password','dbname'); 
extract($_POST);
$user_id=$db->real_escape_string($id);
$status=$db->real_escape_string($status);
$sql=$db->query("UPDATE user SET status='$status' WHERE id='$id'");
echo 1;
?>
```

this is my code for displaying it, on this part everything works fine, when the value are 0 it will display inactive and 1 for active, however when clicking the status theres nothing happen only the notification and reload the page.

```
<td><i data="<?php echo $user['id'];?>" class="status_checks btn
  <?php echo ($user['status'])?
  'btn-success': 'btn-danger'?>"><?php echo ($user['status'])? 'Active' : 'Inactive'?>
 </i></td>
```

Comment: remove the inner quotes from your `query`. should be: `$sql=$db->query("UPDATE user SET status=$status WHERE id=$id");`

Comment: still the same it does not work also @QuietOran

Comment: are you storing any session variables? You say the page reloads, which means the php function works, or at least returns. Is the issue that you're not seeing the HTML reflect the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your code to:

```
$(document).on('click','.status_checks',function(){
  var status = '1';
  var msg = 'Activate';
if($(this).hasClass("btn-success")){
  status = '0';
  msg = 'Deactivate';
 }


  if(confirm("Are you sure to "+ msg)){
    var id= $(this).data('id');
    url = "/ajax.php";
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: url,
      data: {id:id,status:status},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data)
      {   
        console.log(data);
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  }      
});

<?php $db= new mysqli('localhost','root','password','dbname'); 

$user_id=$_POST['id'];
$newStatus=$_POST['$status'];
$sql = "UPDATE user SET status=".$newStatus." WHERE id=".$user_id." 
";
if($db->query($sql) === TRUE){
echo json_encode(1);
}else{
echo json_encode(0);
}

?>




<td><i data-id="<?php echo $user['id'];?>" class="status_checks btn
<?php echo ($user['status'])?
'btn-success': 'btn-danger'?>"><?php echo ($user['status'])? 'Active' : 
'Inactive'?>
</i></td>
```

Comment: Have a try for this then tell me what was the return if 0 or 1.

Comment: change the attribute data to data-id

Comment: I tried to changed the data attribute still the same.

Comment: i think the url . did you check the console? try to put / in the url and i added a console.log at the success of our ajax